# Apache Wicket DropdownChoice default value issue when value is "-1"

Tags: wicket

I am using Ichoicerenderer's overriden class for displaying the values from List in
DropDown.

**cfrList**  is list populated from Database. It is list of type **"CfrInfo"**.
CfrInfo has getCfrSubRule() and getCfrShortDesc() methods.
Problem is, default value when my getCfrSubRule() method returns **-1**.
Under normal circumstances, be default my dropdown shows "Choose One" as selected when page loads.
But when my list has value as "-1" , it always shows "-1" as default values instaed of "Choose One"

Any help will appreciated .Thanks in Aadvance....

Please refer below code...

```
    dropDown = new DropDownChoice("subRuleCode",new PropertyModel(
                  inspectionid,"subRuleInfo"),cfrList,new IChoiceRenderer(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public Object getDisplayValue(Object object)
        {
            CfrInfo info = (CfrInfo) object;
            StringBuffer value = new StringBuffer();
            value.append(info.getCfrShortDesc());
            value.append("(");
            value.append(info.getCfrSubRule());
            value.append(")");
            return value.toString();
        }
        public String getIdValue(Object object, int index)
        {
            if (object instanceof CfrInfo) {
                CfrInfo info = (CfrInfo) object;
                return info.getCfrSubRule();
            }
            return (String)object;
        }         
    }
    );
```

Comment: What is in the `subRuleInfo` field before the component is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand your question.

Are you saying that `CfrInfo.getCfrSubRule()` sometimes returns -1? You will need to return something that is effectively a primary key for `getIdValue()`, so you should not be returning -1.

If on the other hand you are merely trying to change what is displayed in the drop-down when no item is selected, you simply need to provide a property key/value pair in your `WicketApplications.properties` file like:

```
yourDropDown.null = Choose One
```